# Environment variables apparently not being passed to a systemd service invocation

Tags: go, terraform, systemd, systemctl, terragrunt

Here is the case:

I am writing a `go` program.

At some point, the program calls `terragrunt` cli, via `os.Exec()`.

The program is run on a machine having `systemd` version `232`.

Up till know, I have been invoking `terragrunt` with some env vars exposed (required by `terragrunt` as we will see below)

These env vars are passed to the login process by `/etc/profile.d/terragruntvars` as in

```
export TF_VAR_remote_state_bucket=my-bucket-name
```

So when I run in my terminal say `terragrunt plan` and by the appropriate interpolation in my `tf` / `hcl` files, I get something like (this is a `debug` level output, showing the actual `terraform` invocation `terragrunt` ends up performing)

```
terraform init -backend-config=my-bucket-name ...(more flags following)
```

My `go` program (invoking `terragrunt` cli via `os.Exec()`) runs perfectly via `go run main.go`

I decide to make this a `systemd` service as in

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c myprogram
EnvironmentFile=/etc/myprogram/config
User=someuser
Group=somegroup

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The program started failing miserably. By searching the root case I found out that the `TF_VAR_*` variables where never passed to the service when running, so the `terraform` command ended up being like

```
terraform init -backend-config=(this is empty, nothing here)
```

I thought that by explicitly invoking the service via `bash`, i.e. by making `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c myprogram` this would address the problem.

Here come the weird(est) parts.

Adding these vars to `EnvironmentFile=/etc/myprogram/config` **did not have any effect** in the `terragrunt` execution. When I say **no effect**, I mean the variables did become available to the service, however the command is still broken, i.e.

```
terraform init -backend-config=(this is empty, nothing here)
```

However, the `TF_VAR_*` variables **ARE** there. I added an `os.Exec("env")` in my program and it did print them.

This has been driving me nuts so any hint about what might be causing this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just like a shell will not pass it's process ENV VAR's on to child processes:

```
$ X=abc
$ bash -c 'echo $X'   # prints nothing
```

unless you export the environment variable:

```
$ export X
$ bash -c 'echo $X'   # abc
```

similarly with `systemd` and when using `EnvironmentFile`, to export environment variables, use `PassEnvironment` e.g.

```
PassEnvironment=VAR1 VAR2 VAR3
```

From the [docs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man5/systemd.exec.5.html):

> PassEnvironment=
> Pass environment variables set for the system service manager to executed processes.
> Takes a space-separated list of variable names...

Comment: thanks for this suggestion; however as I mentioned in my original question, when I run `os.Exec("env")`, it seems that the variables are available.

Comment: PassEnvironment appears to have no effect on RHEL8/Rocky8.

Comment: PassEnvironment is not working. Environment variables are still not available to the app.